# Highlighting a dynamically created row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a table where a row gets added every time I press a "Add" button. I have an "Edit" button which is placed in the first cell of the newly created row.

I want to highlight the row that is being edited. I know that I can get the current `<tr>` element like

```
var par = $(this).parent().parent();
```

But when I use,

```
par.css('border-color', 'red');
```

It does not change the color.
What mistake am I making and how should I highlight that particular row?

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: try `var par = $(this).closest('tr')`

Comment: Can you show the markup as well?

Comment: You should provide the markup, as it stands now it could be also a problem with zero border width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really about the styling of the `<tr>`. CSS doesn't like to style `<tr>`'s because they really only exist for semantics. In order to add a border to one, you need to make it `display: block;`.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/Xaje7/) and example code.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".edit").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('editting');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**CSS**

```
table tr {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.editting {
    background: #FAA;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Please note how I used an `rgba` color to make the border opaque. There are other ways to do this, but if you leave the border off it causes the table to "jitter."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this` refers to an element within the `tr`, then it will be better to use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) here

```
var par = $(this).closest('tr')
```